# Stop sound running through infinite loop

Tags: android

I am playing a sound infinite time using following code

```
SoundPool sounds = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);  
beepSound = sounds.load(this, R.raw.beep, 1);  
beepSoundStream = sounds.play(beepSound, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0,-1, 1.5f);
```

On some event i want to stop the sound. I am trying

```
sounds.stop(beepSoundStream);
```

I have also tried

```
sounds.stop(beepSound)
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You have your play method set to loop. Change the fifth argument to a 0...

`beepSoundStream = sounds.play(beepSound, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.5f);`

Comment: I need to run it in a loop that's why i have set it to -1

Comment: I even also tried  sounds.setLoop(beepSoundStream, 0);sounds.stop(beepSoundStream);

Comment: Ohh sorry I misread your question, I thought you were trying to get it to stop looping haha... I see what you are going for now. The first way you tried to stop the sound using `sounds.stop(beepSoundStream);` is correct, in fact I just tried that same thing and it worked for me. Hmmm...

Comment: Have you tried calling `pause()` on that stream? Does that work at all?

Comment: pause() is also not working. I have to use MediaPlayer. It is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

`sounds.autoPause()` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
idSound = soundPool.play(soundId, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1f);
```

and for stop soundPool:

```
new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        soundPool.stop(idSound);
                    }
                }, 100);
```

after much trying..this solution works for me!!